# bash -c in subshell gives EOF parsing error

Tags: bash, quoting

Why does the following script work as expected (prints `hello`)

```
#!/bin/bash

foo=$(bash -c 'echo hello')
echo $foo
```

while this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="bash -c 'echo hello'"
foo=$($cmd)
echo $foo
```

gives the following error:

```
hello': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
hello': -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Variables are for data, functions are for code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In,

```
cmd="bash -c 'echo hello'"
$cmd
```

You're not running the `bash -c 'echo hello'` command, you're running the `$cmd` simple command.

That unquoted `$cmd` means invoking the split+glob operator. Here, with the default value of `$IFS`, the content of `$cmd` is split into `bash`, `-c`, `'echo` and `hello'`. So, you're running `bash` with those 4 arguments, it's as if you had typed:

```
bash -c "'echo" "hello'"
```

And that `'echo` code has a missing closing quote (the `hello'` argument goes into the `$0` of that inline script).

If you want to evaluate the content of `$cmd` as shell code, it's

```
eval "$cmd"
```

So:

```
cmd="bash -c 'echo hello'"
foo=$(eval "$cmd")
echo "$foo"
```

Though you could also use your split+glob operator differently:

```
cmd='bash,-c,echo hello'
IFS=, # split on comma
set -f # disable glob
foo=$($cmd)
echo "$foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a look into what is being executed inside `$($cmd)`:

```
$ cmd="bash -c 'echo hello'"
$ foo=$(printf '<%s>' $cmd)
$ echo "$foo"
<bash> <-c> <'echo> <hello'>
```

As you can see, the command line executed is:

```
$ foo=$( "bash" "-c" "'echo" "hello'")
```

One single quote is on one side of the expresion: `"'echo"`, that is parsed as the command to be executed by `bash -c` and it reports (correctly) that a closing single quote `` `'' `` is missing.

One solution is to promote the correct parsing of the command with eval:

```
$ foo=$(eval "printf '<%s>' $cmd"); echo "$foo"
<bash><-c><echo hello>
```

This works:

```
$ foo=$(eval "$cmd"); echo "$foo"
hello
```

---

But the correct idea is that: **“variables store data, functions store code”**.

```
$ cmd(){ bash -c 'echo hello'; }
$ foo=$(cmd); echo "$foo"
hello
```